Find duplicate "group of rows" in pandas DataFrame
How can I find duplicates of a group of rows inside of a DataFrame? Or in other words, how can I find the indices of a specific duplicated DataFrame inside of a larger DataFrame?
The larger DataFrame:



index
0
1




0
0
1


1
2
3


2
4
4


3
0
1


4
2
3


5
2
3


6
0
1



The specific duplicated DataFrame (or group of rows):



index
0
1




0
0
1


1
2
3



Indices I am looking for:



index




0


1


3


4



(Note that the indices of the duplicated DataFrame do not matter, only the values).
import pandas as pd

# larger DataFrame
lrg_df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 4], [0, 1], [2, 3], [2, 3], [0, 1]])

# group of rows (i.e., duplicated DataFrame)
dup_df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3]])

# get indices of lrg_df that contain dup_df
indcs = lrg_df[lrg_df == dup_df].index  # Doesn't work of course


You need to check all combinations with a sliding window, using numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view to create a mask and extend the mask with numpy.convolve:
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

n = len(dup_df)
mask = (swv(lrg_df, n, axis=0)
        == dup_df.to_numpy().T
       ).all((1,2))

out = lrg_df[np.convolve(mask, np.ones(n))>0]

Output:
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
3  0  1
4  2  3

And if you want the indices:
indices = lrg_df.index[np.convolve(mask, np.ones(n))>0]

Output:
Index([0, 1, 3, 4], dtype='int64')

Intermediates:
# swv(lrg_df, n, axis=0) == dup_df.to_numpy().T
array([[[ True,  True],
        [ True,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[ True,  True],
        [ True,  True]],

       [[False,  True],
        [False,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [False, False]]])

# mask
array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False])


Thank you very much for your solution and for editing my example code to match my example table. I think you forgot to reference lrg_df in your out and indices calculations: it should be out = lrg_df[np.convolve(mask, np.ones(n))>0] and indices = lrg_df.index[np.convolve(mask, np.ones(n))>0]

Yes you're right, I forgot to update the name ;)

You can loop through the lrg_df in the old fashion way and find the duplicated groups:
def find_group_duplicates(dataframe, duplicate_group):
    indices = []
    dup_len = len(duplicate_group)

    for i in range(len(dataframe) - dup_len + 1):
        if dataframe.iloc[i:i + dup_len].reset_index(drop=True).equals(duplicate_group):
            indices.extend(range(i, i + dup_len))

    return indices


indices = find_group_duplicates(lrg_df, dup_df)
print(indices)

Output:
[0, 1, 3, 4]


Let's say this is your dataframe:
import pandas as pd

lrg_df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 4], [0, 1], [2, 3],[5, 5]])
print(lrg_df)

   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  4
3  0  1
4  2  3
5  5  5

You can use .drop_duplicates() to get all unique rows only
print(lrg_df.drop_duplicates())

   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  4
5  5  5

Or use .duplicated() to get those duplicate rows only
print(lrg_df[lrg_df.duplicated()])

   0  1
3  0  1
4  2  3

